# Lisp not outputting any result

Tags: lisp

I have a problem as below

```
  (define (problem GP)
   (:domain world)
   (:objects x1 z1 y1)
   (:init (X x1) (Z z1) )
   (:goal (Y y1))
   )
```

and the domain as below

```
  (define (domain GP-domain)
    (:action A
     :paremeters(?x y1)
     :precond((X ?x))
     :effect((Y y1)))
  )
```

I tried running this with a planner but there are no results. By right the action A will be executed as the precondition (X ?x) is met.I have no idea what is wrong.

Another doubt is that when I declare y1 as an object in my object problem, am I allowed to actually 'declare' (Y y1) in the action A as above? Is this correct?

(SOLVED)

I should put it in a simpler way

```
 (define (domain GP-domain)
  (:action A
   :precond X
   :effect Y)

 (define (problem GP-problem)
   (:domain GP-domain)
   (:init X Z)
   (:goal Y)
  )
```

Comment: Which Lisp is this and what libraries, if any, are you using? Also: What's a planner?

Comment: I solved it yesterday. should have leave it as an atom instead of treating it as an object

Comment: Since you've solved it, could you write your solution up as an answer then post and accept it so people in the future with similar problems can learn from your fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should put it in a simpler way

```
 (define (domain GP-domain)
  (:action A
   :precond X
   :effect Y)

 (define (problem GP-problem)
   (:domain GP-domain)
   (:init X Z)
   (:goal Y)
  )
```